# Git won't synchronize file only on one particular machine

Tags: git, proxy, git-checkout

Problem is the following.

My teams code is on bitbucket.org

I cloned the repository on my machine in order it would become local and

`git log`

Shows all the commits correctly, but I have one file with one particular line of code that just doesn't appear (and commit which modified it is present in `git log`).

`git reset --hard <sha>`

Where  is the hash of a commit with this line of code modified does not change it.

I verified the source in the web interface and this line of code is there. I cloned the repo on other device and it is there. The problem occurs only on this one machine.

I created few local branches and made them track remote branches and this file just isn't synchronized with them.

I use this one line of code to compare, but I'm not sure if there are not more errors than this one.

I used to set and unset proxy server on this machine with commands:

`git config --global http.proxy http://<user>:<pass>@<server>:<port>`

`git config --global --unset http.proxy`

In order to be able to work at the University where access is restricted by a proxy. Could this have something in common with this problem? Proxy is unset now, of course.

Comment: What is your OS. If it is windows, please verify if file is open in editor, eclipse or any server running in workspace. Also confirm if there is a case collision. If you are able to clone it, there there is no network related problem. Before doing check out; run "git clean-xfd" to clean untracked files.

Comment: My OS is Debian Stable (3.2.51-1 i686) (the one that cannot get it) and Ubuntu 12.04 (3.5.0-45-generic i686) (the one that does).

I also have runned your command and unfortunately it didn't changed anything. Thank you for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that this file hasn’t been changed locally by running `git status` and making sure it’s not listed.

Then if you know exactly how the line looks like, you should run,

```
git log -S<snippet> /path/to/file
```

to identify the commits that have modified, added or removed the line. (Alternatively you can simply run, `git log /path/to/file` to manually look through all the commits that have changed the file in any way.)

Work the list of commit by inspecting the changes each commit made. For example, you can run `git diff <commit-sha>^! -- <file>` paying attention to the `+/-` lines, that is, what lines have been added and what lines have been removed.